# How to getApplcationContext using BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

This questions is similiar to [How to use getApplicationContext in BroadcastReceiver class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303209/how-to-use-getapplicationcontext-in-broadcastreceiver-class).

But i didn't know how is the previous activity of his doing. So i didn't know how to resolve mine.

This is my activity :

```
public class backgroundApplication extends Activity {
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.background_application);

    /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(backgroundApplication.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(backgroundApplication.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    findViewById(R.id.startAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            start();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancel();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stopAlarmAt10).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAt10();
        }
    });
}
```

for the complete code, i've got it from here : http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

And this is my AlarmReceiver.class extends BroadCastReceiver implements IndoorAtlasListener :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements IndoorAtlasListener
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
initIndoorAtlas();
}
private void initIndoorAtlas() {
    try {
        mIndoorAtlas = IndoorAtlasFactory.createIndoorAtlas(
                getApplicationContext,  // this is the redline
                this, // IndoorAtlasListener
                mApiKey,
                mApiSecret);
    } catch (IndoorAtlasException ex) {
        Log.e("IndoorAtlas", "init failed", ex);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

in you onReceive method

```
initIndoorAtlas(context);
```

and in method

```
private void initIndoorAtlas(Context context) {
    try {
        mIndoorAtlas = IndoorAtlasFactory.createIndoorAtlas(
                context,  // this is the redline
                this, // IndoorAtlasListener
                mApiKey,
                mApiSecret);
    } catch (IndoorAtlasException ex) {
        Log.e("IndoorAtlas", "init failed", ex);
    }
}
```

If method is form implementing interface then use this code..

```
private Context context:
```

and onReceive Method

```
this.context = context;
```

and in you method use context as it is global variable we can access it.

Comment: No that wont work..initIndoorAtlas does not take Context as parameter

Comment: have you tried to modify like this ? As i think you can modify current method as i have said and it will take context as parameter...or you are getting any error ?
ok if this is interface method then see modified answer